# Ruby DateTime: why is 60 seconds being treated as 59 seconds?

Tags: ruby, datetime

Why does the following not throw an error and returns 59 seconds?

```
# 2016-02-02T16:05:59+00:00
DateTime.strptime('02-02-2016 04:05:60 PM', '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
```

I'm running Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.3, with Ruby 2.2.1.

Comment: Strange.  '02-02-2016 04:05:61 PM' raises an exception, '02-02-2016 04:05:xx PM' is OK for xx from '00' to '59'. It's just `"05:60"` that's a problem.

Comment: If you use `Time` instead of `DateTime` you get `"2016-02-02 16:06:00 -0800"`. Which makes more sense.

Comment: @Philip. Why should `Time` and `DateTime` not return the same result?

Comment: A friend of mine suggests it might have to do with leap seconds? But it seems to behave the same regardless of year e.g. 2010 which had no leap seconds :(

Comment: @CarySwoveland My guess is that they are different internally. Different C libraries maybe. Or output formatting. Would have to dig into the ruby source to know for sure. Heck, could be platform specific if they are simply passing to the OS's strftime library.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `61` never occurs.

Comment: What @hobbs said makes sense I suppose. Would be nice if there were some Ruby documentation around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for it is due to the implementation of `strptime` at the lower levels, [which is what the documentation references.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)

> `%S`     The second (0-60; 60 may occur for leap seconds; earlier also 61 was allowed).

There *may* or *may not* be a leap second at that moment in time, so the library *allows* you to pass in 60.  It's smart enough to work out if it needs to add the leap second.

Comment: That makes sense — thanks. However, I can't seem to find a mentions of leap seconds in the documentation link you provided. I see `%S - Second of the minute (00..59)` though.

Comment: According to hobbs' comment to my answer, this is not true.

Comment: `DateTime.strptime('2015-6-30T23:59:60+0')
# => #<DateTime: 2015-06-30T23:59:59+00:00 ((2457204j,86399s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`

Comment: POSIX definitions contradict the definition of UTC as broadcast.  In the broadcast signals of UTC the duration of one second is determined by cesium atoms, the duration of one day is determined by the rotation of the earth, and the two durations are not related.  POSIX chose to use UTC but to define the second and day with durations that are related. Broadcast UTC uses leap seconds and POSIX says they do not happen, so the API cannot be self-consistent.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because unlike February 29, which is predictable when it exists and when it doesn't, existence of the second 60 is irregular and is only decided about six months in advance, so it is impractical/impossible to code that in the library (especially for future times). Hence, it is allowed in general, and it is approximated to the closest second according to the information available at the point of its evaluation. You don't want the same argument string to return an error or not depending on when it is evaluated.

Comment: I think that it's this plus the fact that a DateTime's internal storage format is one that can't actually distinguish between :59 and :60 anyway (many formats that use seconds-from-epoch or seconds-from-beginning-of-day have this flaw), so it gets silently converted to :59 before anything can raise an error. Even if I pass a date string (`30-06-2015 07:59:60 PM`) that corresponds to a leap second in my local timezone, it still gets converted to :59:59.

Comment: @hobbs I see. That is likely the answer to the second part of the question.